# Cron executes old version of script

Tags: 12.04, cron

I defined crontab job by means of:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

As I can see it is listed when I type:

```
sudo crontab -l
```

and it's listed as well when I type:

```
run-parts --test /etc/cron.monthly
```

---

Than I modified script (only script content, without it's name). My script send an email and I modified email content.

Unfortunately, for some reason previous version of my script is executed (I receive and old email).
I even restarted cron:

```
sudo service cron restart
```

but it doesn't help.
I've tried to remove and add again mentioned script to cron, but it doesn't help as well.

I use Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS

Comment: You are mixing it up, you have entered an entry by `crontab -e` and also put the script in `cron.monthly`..`cron.monthly` automatically executes scripts in there every month..additionally you have made a new `cron` task by editing `root`'s `crontab`..may be the spool has kept the old script as it is in the month's crontab..also no need for restarting `cron`, it gets the modifications automatically..

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue on Ubuntu 18.4 LTS.

Cron kept old version of my script and didn't seem to see the script was updated.

Solved this by doing `sudo service cron stop` and then `sudo service cron start`.

`sudo service cron restart` didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange that the script is listed with the `run-parts` command in `/etc/cron.monthly`, that suggests that the script is somehow in that directory.

Perhaps you have a copy of the old version in the `/etc/cron.monthly` directory?

It may be worth removing the crontab entries, and checking that there's nothing in `/etc/cron.monthly`, then try renaming the script and putting it back in your crontab to see if it executes correctly.

If it does work correctly, you can try to change the name back afterwards.

Comment: Okay, I removed script from 

/etc/cron.monthly 

and remove it from 

crontab -e. 

Then I moved script to the new location under new file name. 
Again I edited crontab and added new script name. 
When I type 

sudo crontab -l 

I see 

0 13 * * 1 /mnt/New_File_name

However, today old script has been executed :-(

Is it possible that I mixed for example anacron here? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do a file search as 'root' and locate all instances of your script.  Remove all those you do not want.  When you have only the version of the script you want to run through cron, then restart cron.

Comment: sudo find / -name 'MyScriptName'
returns me only one result

(
where MyScriptName:
0 13 * * 1 /mnt/MyScriptName
in 
    sudo crontab -l
)

Comment: So, unfortunately, your suggestion, doesn't help me a lot (but thanks anyway).

Comment: Any chance on modifying the new script, add an echo "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" to be certain of what script is being called?  (Your old script, of course, will not have this echo output.)  The idea here is to print the script name and full path.  The code `basename "$0"` may also work as well.